# 'base_tags' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of:

Tags: python, django

Hello I get this error for create new custom template tags in django
how i can debug my code?

it's my template tags:

```
from django import template
from ..models import Category

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def title():
    return "any thing"
```

it's my HTML code:

```
{% load base_tags%}
             <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">{% title %}</a>
```

it's my error:
'base_tags' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of: admin_list admin_modify admin_urls cache i18n l10n log static tz

I run webserver in terminal but for again it's doesn't work true

Answer (score 1):

You got this error because you have not added this tag in settings.py file

change this:

```
@register.simple_tag
```

To this:

```
@register.simple
```

And in templates:

```
{% load simple_tags %}
```

And in settings.py file:

```
'libraries':{
                'simple_tags': 'templatetags.simple',
            }
```

If templatetags directory inside an app then you must add appname in libraries

```
'libraries':{
                'filter_tags': 'your_appname.templatetags.simple',
            }
```

EX:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
            'libraries':{
                'simple_tags': 'your_appname.templatetags.simple', #Added here
            }
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: Hello I do it but my error doesn't fix what should I do?

Comment: I updated my answer try that. it should work now

Comment: I did that but it still didn't work‍♂️
I don't know whyt it's not ok , this error really made me angary

Comment: @MahyarMohamadpour I have solved this error today. checkout my updated answer